# Template 10: Modal not closing

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, uwp, template10

I want to close the modal of Template 10 on the Shell view with a button in that modal. The close function in the Shell.xaml.cs is triggered and IsModal and HasError are switched to false, but the modal dialog stays active.

The code I used:

**LandingpageViewModel:**

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
{
    var i = await getMuscleScores();
    if(i == null)
        ShowError();
}

public void ShowError()
{
    Views.Shell.SetError(true);
}
```

**Shell.xaml.cs:**

```
public bool IsModal { get; set; } = false;
public bool HasError { get; set; } = false;
public string ErrorText { get; set; } = "Something went wrong...";
public static void SetError(bool error, string text = null)
{
    WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        if (error)
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        else
            BootStrapper.Current.UpdateShellBackButton();

        Instance.IsModal = error;
        Instance.IsBusy = !error;
        Instance.HasError = error;
        Instance.ErrorText = text == null ? "Something went wrong..." : text;

        Instance.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(Instance, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsModal)));
        Instance.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(Instance, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HasError)));
        Instance.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(Instance, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ErrorText)));
    });
}

public void HideError(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetError(false);
}
```

**Shell.xaml:**

```
<Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Height="32">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{x:Bind IsBusy, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConv}}">
                <ProgressRing Width="16" Height="16"
                        Margin="12,0" Foreground="White"
                        IsActive="{x:Bind IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind BusyText, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind HasError, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConv}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Oops!" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ErrorText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Continue" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="HideError"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
```

Another thing what I tried to find the problem is this in **LandingPageViewModel:**

```
ShowError();
await Task.Delay(5000);
HideError();
```

And this gives me the same result that the modal dialog stays open. So it looks like something goes wrong with using different threads I think. Does someone know a sollution for this problem? BTW: I am using the latest version of Template 10
    enter code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close the modal of Template 10, we need set `ModalDialog.IsModal` property to "false". As your XAML code is incomplete, I guess you are using Template 10 Minimal template. In the template it uses `IsBusy` to set `ModalDialog.IsModal` property. But it seems you are using `IsModal` in your code-behind to control `ModalDialog`, so you can bind this property to `ModalDialog.IsModal` as following:

```
<Controls:ModalDialog IsModal="{x:Bind IsModal, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Controls:ModalDialog.Content>
    ...
    </Controls:ModalDialog.Content>
    <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
        <Grid>
            <Viewbox Height="32">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{x:Bind IsBusy, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConv}}">
                    <ProgressRing Width="16" Height="16"
                        Margin="12,0" Foreground="White"
                        IsActive="{x:Bind IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind BusyText, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Viewbox>
            <StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind HasError, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConv}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Oops!" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ErrorText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Button Content="Continue" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="HideError"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
</Controls:ModalDialog>
```

Then when you tap the `Continue` button, the modal should disappear.

Comment: I use IsModal as binding  to my modalDialog. So this is not the fault.

Comment: @Bouthoorn I tested your code with a Template 10 Minimal project, it works well. You can check my repo at [GitHub](https://github.com/Z-Jay/Template10MinimalTest). As I don't know the detail of your `Landingpage`, I just use `Views.Shell.SetError(true);` in `MainPageViewModel`. I think the issue is not in the code you've posted. It would be better if you can share a sample that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your project. I found the problem! I forgot to add INotifyPropertyChanged to the Shell.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic dialog implementation.

```
<Controls:ModalDialog x:Name="ModalContainer" 
                      CanBackButtonDismiss="False"
                      DisableBackButtonWhenModal="True" 
                      IsModal="False" 
                      ModalBackground="Blue">

    <!-- content -->
    <Controls:ModalDialog.Content>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenu />
    </Controls:ModalDialog.Content>

    <!-- modal content -->
    <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>
        <views:Busy x:Name="BusyView" />
    </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalContent>

    <!-- optional transition -->
    <Controls:ModalDialog.ModalTransitions>
        <ContentThemeTransition />
    </Controls:ModalDialog.ModalTransitions>

</Controls:ModalDialog>
```

You can implement this however you like, but here's how I do it.

```
public static void SetBusy(bool busy, string text = null)
{
    WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        Instance.BusyView.BusyText = text;
        Instance.ModalContainer.IsModal = Instance.BusyView.IsBusy = busy;
    });
}
```

The Dispatcher is important because it is static and can be called from any thread. Note that I customize the `busyText` and `isBusy` values of the Busy view - but that's going to unique to your approach. The important part is where `Instance.ModalContainer.IsModal` gets set to true and false. This is the only thing that controls the state of the `ModalDialog` control.

Hopefully, my complete sample will help.

> http://aka.ms/template10

Best of luck.